# Two android devices setup socket communication via USB

Tags: android, sockets, adb, usb-otg

I want to setup  socket communication between Android Tablet and Android cellphone via USB.
My Idea is using the " ADB foward " after the two devices connect  each other viar usb otg.
Or do you have any better ideas?

### It seems that both two devices need to support OTG before they could see each other.

So my question is do I really need  two android devices with otg support to do my job?

Answer (score 0):

I have once tried setup socket communication between my cellphone and emulators using the " ADB foward ". Maybe you can try this.

Comment: thanks,do you mean use AndroVM [link](http://androvm.org/blog/download/)? but what if you want to connect two android devices not emulator? I found when the tablet with otg support connects with my pandaboard (also with otg support),they just don't recognize each other . i also tried to connect my XIAOMI 1S with Pandaboard, it output the voltage was two low.